# Basic NGINX, uWSGI configuration running locally only delivers 404

Tags: nginx, uwsgi, flask

My Flask app runs through uWSGI, and I am using a TCP socket to talk to NGINX. The configuration is very basic:

**application.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    location / {
        uwsgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include uwsgi_params;
    }
}
```

I specify the TCP socket in my .ini:

**uwsgi.ini**

```
[uwsgi]
socket = 127.0.0.1:9000

# remove the socket once disconnected
vacuum = true

module = wsgi
callable = app
processes = 4
threads = 2
master = 1
```

And my module:

**wsgi.py**

```
from app import create_app

app = create_app('config/development.py')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

127.0.0.1:80/ only returns 404 errors (and NGINX 502 errors when uWSGI is not running).

How can I get uWSGI and NGINX to speak to one another? How can uWSGI serve the Flask app through NGINX?

Comment: Check your error log.

Comment: error.log gives me: `[notice] 4xxxx#0: signal process started`

Comment: I solved the problem by setting the Flask config "SERVER_NAME" to a domain configured in my OS X host file "applicationlocal", and then changed my application.conf to: `listen 80; server_name applicationlocal`. Hope this helps someone!

Comment: @LelandLater Please write it as an answer, even if it's ur own question.

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by changing my Flask configuration to specify the server:

**config/development.py**

```
...
SERVER_NAME = 'applicationlocal'
```

and then specified that server in the NGINX configuration:

**application.conf**

```
location / {
     listen 80;
     server_name applicationlocal;
}
```

I had previously edited the OS X host file to match 127.0.0.1 to "applicationlocal"; now I can access the application at "applicationlocal:80/" but not "127.0.0.1:80/".